# Не могу поставить несколько переменных в bot message

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, python-telegram-bot

Всем привет! Не понимаю почему вылазит ошибка когда я ввожу команду start. Ниже прилогаю код.
Суть проблемы в том что я хочу использовать несколько переменных в одном сообщении, пока что выкручиваюсь тем что отправляю переменные разными сообщениями.

```
import telebot

a = '1'
b = '2'

bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])  
def start_command(message):  
    bot.send_message(  
    message.chat.id,
        a,b)

bot.polling( non_stop = True)
```

Вот текст ошибки:

```
2023-02-09 18:49:36,163 (__init__.py:1083 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "Threaded polling exception: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: unsupported parse_mode"
2023-02-09 18:49:36,203 (__init__.py:1085 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "Exception traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nazar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1074, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "C:\Users\Nazar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 148, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
  File "C:\Users\Nazar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 91, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nazar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 6428, in _run_middlewares_and_handler
    result = handler['function'](message)
  File "D:\python\test2.py", line 10, in start_command
    bot.send_message(
  File "C:\Users\Nazar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1549, in send_message
    apihelper.send_message(
  File "C:\Users\Nazar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 264, in send_message
    return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload, method='post')
  File "C:\Users\Nazar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 162, in _make_request
    json_result = _check_result(method_name, result)
  File "C:\Users\Nazar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 189, in _check_result
    raise ApiTelegramException(method_name, result, result_json)
telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: unsupported parse_mode
"
```

Comment: Что хоть за ошибка то?

Comment: @SwaD https://imgur.com/a/qcdRaoN

Comment: Смешно. Текст ошибки вставьте в ваш вопрос именно текстом! Для редактирования вопроса нажмите кнопку "Править"

Comment: @SwaD Вставил, надеюсь поможете с решением проблемы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что у функции **send_message** третий аргумент это  *parse_mode* и скорее всего не '2'.

[image: telebot init.py]

Если хотите несколько переменных использовать то сделайте их конкатена́цию.

Типа так result = a + b

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, result)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!